# How do I install shutter?

Tags: parrot-os

I am trying to install shutter as I want to take screenshots while learning in  parrot.

A web search said shutter is the best so I want to try this.

step 1 sudo apt-get install shutter
response -  Package 'shutter' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the PPA

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/shutter`
2. Update the repo

   `suo apt-get update`
3. Reform Installation

   `sudo apt-get install shutter`